# Select from table using resolute from another query

Tags: mysql

You see, t1 and t2 have some similar rows, on the first query  I select the ones that don't match, I used the following Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.usr_id
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.usr_id != t2.usr_id
AND t1.event =  '$event'
AND t1.client =  '$client'
GROUP BY t1.usr_id
```

Now I want to use the result from the query above to select * from t3 matching usr_id.
I'v tried the answers given to other almost similar questions but none of them is subtracting from one query and using results to obtain data from a second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t3.usr_id FROM t3 WHERE t3.usr_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT t1.usr_id
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.usr_id != t2.usr_id
AND t1.event =  '$event'
AND t1.client =  '$client'
GROUP BY t1.usr_id)
```

but it may be slow, than:

```
SELECT table.usr_id
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT t1.usr_id
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.usr_id != t2.usr_id
AND t1.event =  '$event'
AND t1.client =  '$client'
GROUP BY t1.usr_id ) as table
JOIN t3 ON t3.usr_id = table.usr_id
```

Comment: error in SQL syntax 'TABLE JOIN t3 ON registro.id = table.urs_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 7

Comment: what "registro" ? If it's "t3" table then you should be change it everywhere in query

Comment: Thanks' and sorry for the delayed response, I used the first suggestion and it worked fin, you're right its slow, I'm trying to make the second option work, but I must be doing something wrong :)

Comment: Got it, It's Perfect, I just changed the SELECT column from table.usr_id to t3.* and it was fast, efficient and cool  Thank's @vrtx64 This is most helpful